# bat file doesn't pause execution

Tags: windows, node.js, batch-file, cmd

I'm using a **bat** file to run my **nodejs** app in **windows 7**. The **bat** file contains following lines,

```
cd "C:/dev/nodeapp/"
npm start
pause
```

But the **bat** file doesn't pause. Because of that I can't see the errors on cmd when **nodejs** throws errors. I tried `cmd /k` instead of `pause`, it doesn't work either.

Anybody knows a way to pause the bat file execution here?

*I notice that the problem is with the line `npm start`. When I remove that line the `pause` works..!*

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not pause because in windows `npm` is a batch file (`npm.cmd`). Directly invocation of a batch file from inside a batch file transfers the execution to the called one, and does not return to the caller. You need to use `call` command

```
cd "C:/dev/nodeapp/"
call npm start
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pause here is incorrect
try this:
 npn stop